# How to show local singapore time using php?

Tags: php

I wants to display singapore time. I have tried out like this,

```
<?php echo date("l dS of F Y h:i:s A");
```

but when inserting this value to a column of data table (with datatype-datetime ) it shows the time as 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to insert with mysql [date time format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html). In PHP which is equivalent to,

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

**Note:** Issue is not related to Time Zone, but you can set default time zone to Singapore using 
`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');` on top of your file.

Comment: but I need singapore time

Answer (score 2):

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore'); 
$todayDate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
```

[look at this for default_time_rimezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

to get the timezone.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to display current timestamp. Either you use "localtime" PHP method to display the current local time in an Array OR you can use DateTimeZone to display the specific timezone date-time. Here is the code ..

```
<?php
// Echo the local time in an array.
print_r(localtime(time(),true));

// Set the manual time zone if you wants to display other time zone dateTime (For Example : Singapore).
$from = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$to   = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore');
$currDate     = new DateTime('now', $from);
$currDate->setTimezone($to);
echo $currDate->format('Y/m/j H:i:s');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

write `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');` before displaying the date.

for inputting the value into database, use the `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` format in php to match the column, or make the column type as `varchar(50)` to store date as string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

// Current date/time in the specified time zone.
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

Answer (score 0):

try with date_default_timezone_set()

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Paris' ) ;
 echo date( "l dS of F Y h:i:s A" ) ;

 date_default_timezone_set( 'Asia/Singapore' ) ;
 echo date( "l dS of F Y h:i:s A" ) ;
?>
```